# jquery selector with a class and variable id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element id in an variable say `elementId`. Now i want to select the element from a class say `.control-menu` which have an id equal to element id.

I am trying it like

```
$('.control-menu "#"+elementId')
```

I am getting syntax error. can someone tell me the right way to do this?

Comment: try to use `$('#'+elementid+'.control-menu')`

Comment: Are you looking for an element with that ID *within* another element that has the class `control-menu`, or are you looking for an element with that ID that also, itself, has the class `control-menu`?

Comment: Ya, what are you looking for? Your question is really ambiguous

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#' + elementId + '.control-menu');
```

Would match `<div id="elementID" class="control-menu"></div>`

An `id` is unique; select by that first and then check to see if it has a matching class-name.

Incidentally, your original selector was searching for the element with the `id` that has an ancestor element with the class of `.control-menu`.

If the element with the `id` for which you're searching *is* a descendant element of another with the class of `.control-menu`, then:

```
$('.control-menu #'+elementid);
```

Would match `<div class="control-menu"><div id="elementID"></div></div>`

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP's code seems to want to do, which is find the element only if it's *within* something with the `control-menu` class (rather than finding something that *has* the `control-menu` class).

Comment: I read the description as wanting to find an element with that `id` from a collection of elements with the `class`-name. Though it's perhaps ambiguous.

Comment: what could the reason to use an id and class selector together

Comment: The only reason I can think of if you want to do something if the element is appearing in a particular location in the dom.... are there any other reasons

Comment: The reason to find an element by its `id` *and* its `class` is perhaps to check for the 'state' of that element (as affected by JavaScript changing a class-name to reflect an interaction, or its lack), or to find it only on certain pages under certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

since you have an id you can just use the id selector because id of an element will be unique

```
$('#'+elementId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

```
$('#' + elementId + '.control-menu');
```

An `id` is unique; select by that first and then check to see if it has a matching class-name.

Incidentally, your original selector was searching for the element with the `id` that has an ancestor element with the class of `.control-menu`.

If the element with the `id` for which you're searching *is* a descendant element of another with the class of `.control-menu`, then:

```
$('.control-menu #'+elementid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.control-menu #'+elementId);
```

or simply

```
$('#'+elementId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as:

```
 $('#'+ elementId )
```

the class is not needed at all for `ID` is already unique in your page.

---

**Your question title says: `jquery selector with a class and variable id`...**

If you're about to select a `CLASS` that has the same name as the desired variable `ID` than go for:

```
$('.control-menu .'+ elementId )
//               ^------------------ note the class selector
```

Otherwise, I repeat you **cannot** have multiple `ID` elements in one single page.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.control-menu #'+elementId)
```